# Why we Put INSERT IN DECLARE TABLE in Linked Server report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

```
DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE
(
    test
)

SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT something'

INSERT INTO @ReturnTable EXEC(@SqlQuery) AT LinkedServer

SELECT * FROM @ReturnTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the Select from the LinkedServer  like this

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
(test)
SELECT test from [AliasOfLinkserver].Database.Schema.Table

Select * from @ReturnTable
```

When you execute a Select _statment from a @variable use the sp_executesql stored procedur  which is provided by the SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(500)
SET @SQL ='Select * from YourTable'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```